# Problems that involves two facts in the definition of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, vector-spaces, axioms

I have two small questions that I can't solve.

So, there are 8 axioms for vector spaces. One of them is that $1 \cdot a = a$ for all $a \in V$ and of course $1$ is multiplicative identity in $\mathbb{F}.$

How can I be sure this axiom cannot be derived from other 7 axioms?

Also, why is there no definition of $\alpha a= a\alpha, \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{F}, \forall a \in V$? Why is multiplication of scalars and vectors not defined in commutative way?

Comment: What does $a\alpha$ *mean* when $\alpha\in\Bbb F$ and $a\in V$?

Comment: Ok, I thought this is the problem... It's not defined? $\cdot : \mathbb{F} × V \rightarrow V$ but not $V × \mathbb{F}$... Why isn't defined commutativity of vector-scalar multiplication?

Comment: If you are aware of a way of defining that, then please provide it.

Comment: José, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V=\Bbb F^2$. For each $\alpha\in\Bbb F$ and each $(a_1,a_2)\in\Bbb F^2$, define$$\alpha.(a_1,a_2)=(\alpha a_1,0).$$Then $1.(1,1)\ne(1,1)$, but all other aximoms hold for this structure.

Comment: Can you please be more detailed?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't see what's missing. Every single vector space axiom holds for this structure, except that you dont always have $1.a=a$. Therefore, this axiom cannot be deduced from the other ones.

Comment: Can you please add why is $a \cdot \alpha$ not defined for $a \in V, \alpha \in \mathbb{F}$?

Comment: Simply because nobody ever defined it.

Comment: Yes, but why? You are professional mathematician so I am sure you know why mathematicians think $a \alpha$ is not important or why it can cause problems.

Comment: I don't *know*, but I suspect that the natural definition would be $\alpha a=a\alpha$, and this would make it useless. It's not really a new concept.

Comment: By above "define" you meant "such that"?

Comment: I meant define $\alpha(a_1,a_2)$ as $(\alpha a_1,0)$.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. Thanks

Comment: In ordinary $\mathbb{F}^n$ arithmetic $\alpha(a_1, a_2)$ is defined to be $(\alpha a_1, \alpha a_2)$ so I was confused...